# how can i change format (aesthetics) of gtable in gWidgets?

Tags: r, gwidgets

i want change the format of a table in gWidgets R, show vertical lines, change background color.

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")

w     <- gwindow("Example")
g     <- ggroup(cont=w)
table <- gtable(mtcars,cont=g)
```

with gtable function no shows vertical lines for separate columns in the table

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")

w     <- gwindow("Example")
g     <- ggroup(cont=w)
table <- gdf(mtcars,cont=g)
```

and gdf adds a new column of rownames, that i dont need besides gdf changes the background color to "orange" or similar , how can i change or modify aesthetics in a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the underlying Gtk widget with: `tbl <- getToolkitWidget(table)`. From there you can call whatever RGtk2 method you want. You will need to load that package first though.

Comment: i add the grid lines table, using this code: `gtkTreeViewSetGridLines(getToolkitWidget(table),grid.lines=3)`